# What are some practical applications of successive differentiation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, taylor-expansion, applications

Before starting to learn something, I always wonder whats its application. So would you please give some practical examples of application of **Successive differentiation** and concepts related to it such as **Taylor's series**?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you need a higher derivative, you have to get there through successive differentiation. For example, if $s(t)$ is the position of a particle at time $t$, then $\frac{d^3s(t)}{dt^3}$ is the "jerk". To get it, you have to compute $\frac{ds(t)}{dt}$, $\frac{d^2s(t)}{dt^2}$, and then $\frac{d^3s(t)}{dt^3}$.